Xaphoon mouthpiece is round, clarinet and saxophone mouthpieces are pointy. How does it affect the sound?
The end of a Xaphoon mouthpiece has a rounded tip (fingertip for scale)

Clarinet and saxophone mouthpieces, on the other hand, are both pointy, though in different ways:
picture of a saxophone mouthpiece
picture of a clarinet mouthpiece
The Xaphoon FAQ says that the round mouthpiece "is responsible for the instrument's full-bodied sound" and "allows a greater range of expressiveness". But what happens acoustically, how exactly does its form affect the sound, and why woudln't it be possible to achieve the same sound with a clarinet-like or a saxophone-like mouthpiece?

The external form of the mouthpiece is irrelevant, what matters is the internal form.

@PiedPiper the internal shape of the Xaphoon mouthpiece simpliy follows its external shape (so it's rounded and concave)
